# eventhandler on button in wpf process while any other click on form is queued

Tags: c#, wpf

. I am quite new to WPF and have a question regarding the queuing of event handler. In the application that I am developing using WPF have the following code on the click of a button

```
private void ButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
  try 
  {
     Cursor = Cursors.Wait;                 
     Processor.UpdateData(); 
  }
  catch (RemoteConnection x)
  {
    ShowConnectionError(this, x);
  }
  finally
  {
            Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
   }
```

When I click on the this button, the method Processor.UpdateData(), starts processing and cursor is set to hour glass. Now in the meantime if user presses any other button on the screen or type in the textbox, that is done immediately after the processing of the above event handler. It seems these events are queued in dispatcher queue. Can you please help me to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Well to avoid such scenario i.e. user should not be able to click or generate another event while one is already going on what you can do is something like this

```
  private void ButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       //disable button here so no more clicking until processing is done
       //start a backgroundworker that will do the processing
    }

   BackgroundWorker()
   {
       try 
       {
          Cursor = Cursors.Wait;                 
          Processor.UpdateData(); 
       }
       catch (RemoteConnection x)
       {
          ShowConnectionError(this, x);
       }
       finally
       {
          Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
          //enable button again using Dispatcher
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

What *exactly* are you trying to avoid? Fundamentally, it's a bad idea to block the UI thread for any significant length of time. It would be better to disable any controls you don't want to raise events, then launch the work on a different thread. When it's finish, marshal back to the UI thread using `Dispatcher`, update the UI, and then re-enable the controls you disabled before.

Comment: Jon, Consider the example, if user presses Update Button then event handler for update button click is raised and executed. Now if user presses the Delete Button then immediately after completing the update, the event handler for Delete button is raised. I want to avoid the situation when event handler of one button is executing and in the meantime no other event be raise(like key_press in text box, or button click).

Comment: @GeekM: That would be avoided by taking exactly my advice: disable the delete button, launch the update work on a different thread (so that the UI remains responsive for moving, resizing etc) and then re-enable the delete button when the update has finished. You don't want to disable *all* events, including redraw, resize etc - you should be selective about what you disable.